# How to debug maven tests remotely

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project. I want to debug tests that run during the project assembly. I run maven from cli

```
mvnDebug -DforkCount=0 test
```

Then I could successfully connect with remote debugger to the running jvm from Intellij. All necessary breakpoints are set. But it wouldn't stop at the breakpoints. Build successful and that is all.

This command works properly though

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
```

But I need to do it with the first.

Comment: Are you sure that you connect to correct JVM? I guess that you connect to JVM that runs maven itself once tests run in separate JVM.

Comment: Doesn't -DforkCount=0 option ensures that maven and all the tests run in the same jvm?

Comment: All tests indeed run in the same JVM. I am not sure howerver that it shares vm with build.

Comment: @AlexR DforkMode=never worked for me, but I don't understand why -DforkCount did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not override plugin configuration so version 2.12 was used. The option that I needed was -DforkMode=never. Since 2.14 this option is deprecated and -DforkCount=0 should be used instead. http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Answer (score 0):

You need [the debugForkedProcess](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#debugForkedProcess) option to surefire.

Comment: Doesn't -DforkCount=0 option ensures that maven and all the tests run in the same jvm? So I should be able to debug them as well?

Comment: depends on version of surefire and 12 other options. If you post your entire surefire config ...